# Active directory LDAP SSL over udp

Tags: ssl, active-directory, udp

We recently implemented our AD to run tcp/ip over SSL/TLS. But when using Wireshark we can see that the AD also communicates in clear text over udp(CLDAP)? Is it possible to force the AD to use SSL/TLS when using udp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UDP is used to send LDAP pings in various scenarios. In general, Windows won't use the LDAP/S endpoints you enabled for any native functions. It will sign/seal however over the regular 389/3268 ports.

Answer (score 0):

SASL - Sign and seal is opportunistic.   They will attempt to negotiate SASL but if the requesting system is not equipped, it will fail back to SIMPLE (insecure) ldap.   You can set registry to refuse SIMPLE, but be careful, doing so will break apps that have not been remediated.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirements-for-windows-kb4520412-ef185fb8-00f7-167d-744c-f299a66fc00a

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NTDS\Parameters

LdapEnforceChannelBinding = 2

Will refuse simple LDAP.  Do only after you have remediated clients

LdapEnforceChannelBinding = 1

Will log 2889 events so you can find clients that would otherwise be excluded but will ALLOW simple LDAP.

Note LDAP is integral in AD.   There are 3 (4) versions of the protocol.

Anonymous: Used for service locators by all windows machines.   No Authentication is necessary so is considered secure.   UDP and TCP 389

SIMPLE: Old simple plain-text authentication. TCP 389   Should be avoided.   This is considered to be a security risk

SASL negotiated Authentication.  TCP 389  - Client and server negotiate secure communications channel before credentials are presented.   This is supported by default by all modern windows platforms, but must be enabled explicitly in JAVA and many non-windows server platforms.   In Linux this might be called negotiated TLS or Start-TLS.

Finally there is explicitly Encrypted or Secure LDAP (LDAPS). TCP 636 and is Analogous to HTTPS.  Internet X.509 certificates are installed on the LDAP server and used to negotiate a secure channel with the client machine.  All communications are encrypted.  Note LDAPS makes use of Load Balancers tricky.   You must install a cert on the load balancer, otherwise you will get cert mismatch errors.